# Screenshot behind a full screen Form results in a black screen

Tags: delphi, screenshot, fullscreen, vcl

I want to capture an image of a desktop that ignores my form when captured. I like [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18849877/9210291), but have not been able to capture the desktop content, only a **black screen**.

[image: Image of form with blank black content]

So, I need of help to try fix this trouble.

Here is my version with little changes:

```
private
    { Private declarations }
    DesktopBMP: TBitmap;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd( var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd ); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
DesktopBMP := TBitmap.Create;
  DesktopBMP.SetSize( Screen.Width, Screen.Height );
  DoubleBuffered := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Width := 0;
  Height := 0;
  Width := Screen.Width;
  Height := Screen.Height;
end;

procedure TForm1.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  //Canvas.Draw( 0, 0, DesktopBMP );
  DesktopBMP.SaveToFile('c:\tela.bmp');
end;

procedure TForm1.WMEraseBkgnd( var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd );
var
  DesktopDC: HDC;
  DesktopHwnd: Hwnd;
  DesktopCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  DesktopHwnd := GetDesktopWindow;
  DesktopDC := GetDC( DesktopHwnd );
  try
    DesktopCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
    DesktopCanvas.Handle := DesktopDC;
    DesktopBMP.Canvas.CopyRect( Rect( 0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height ), DesktopCanvas, Rect( 0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height ) );
  finally
    DesktopCanvas.Free;
    ReleaseDc( DesktopHwnd, DesktopDC );
  end;
  Message.Result := 1;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg, then not is possible erase this black screen on Form? **WM_ERASEBKGND** works fine, but generate a black screen (on background of Form) and not can see screenshot of desktop.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, my goal is see behind a full screen Form (already was made) but the trouble here is that instead of background of Form stay clean, generates a black color and this is showed on result of screen capture like you can see above. Now i want know if exists some possibility to remove this black part on Form (without hide and show Form again) showed on result of screenshot?

Comment: You are telling Windows that you took care of erasing the background with `Message.Result := 1;` but your code doesn't do anything apart from copying the Desktop canvas to your bmp. What happens if you comment out that line?

Comment: @nil, `What happens if you comment out that line?`. Nothing.

Comment: The reason for the black screen in the image is possibly/probably due to the code in `OnTimer`: `Width := 0; Width := Screen.Width;` (and the same for height). To confirm, outcomment the settings to 0. This might give you only one screenshot and it will not be a final solution, but it will confirm the problem. Then you will need to find another way to trigger updating the screenshot. Btw, saving a file in every paint event of a form doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, yes confirmed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution based on the code you presented.

The overlay form is a borderless one (`BorderStyle = bsNone`), and it has two buttons, one to take a screenshot of the underlying screen and one to terminate the application (as we have no buttons in the caption).

**The main changes to your code are**

Two private fields in the form

```
DoSnapShot: boolean; // to control when to copy the screen
ScreenRect: TRect;   // to hold the rectangle of the overlay
```

and a procedure

```
procedure TakeScreenShot;
```

`TakeScreenShot`replaces the `OnTimer` handler you had in your code, and adds setting the boolean `DoSnapShot = True` just before resetting the `Width` and `Height`

`WMEraseBkgnd` is modified to only attempt to copy the underlying screen if `DoSnapShot = True`.

Complete code follows

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ScreenBtn: TButton;
    ExitBtn: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScreenBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ExitBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    DesktopBMP: TBitmap;
    DoSnapShot: boolean; // to control when to copy the screen
    ScreenRect: TRect;   // to hold the rectangle of the overlay
    procedure TakeScreenShot;
    procedure WMEraseBkgnd( var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd ); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.ScreenBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TakeScreenShot;
end;

procedure TForm3.ExitBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Left := 0;
  Top := 0;
  Width := Screen.Width;
  Height := Screen.Height-10;

  ScreenRect := Rect(Left, Top, Width, Height);

  DesktopBMP := TBitmap.Create;
  DesktopBMP.SetSize( Width, Height );
end;

procedure TForm3.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.Draw( 0, 0, DesktopBMP );
end;

procedure TForm3.TakeScreenShot;
begin
  Width := 0;   // will not trigger copying
  Height := 0;  //
  DoSnapShot := True;  // now enable copying the underlying screen
  Width := ScreenRect.Width;    //
  Height := ScreenRect.Height;  // and trigger it in WMEraseBkgnd
end;

procedure TForm3.WMEraseBkgnd(var Message: TWMEraseBkgnd);
var
  DesktopDC: HDC;
  DesktopHwnd: Hwnd;
  DesktopCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  if DoSnapShot then
  begin
    DoSnapShot := False; // Disable repeated copying
    DesktopHwnd := GetDesktopWindow;
    DesktopDC := GetDC( DesktopHwnd );
    try
      DesktopCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
      DesktopCanvas.Handle := DesktopDC;
      DesktopBMP.Canvas.CopyRect( ScreenRect , DesktopCanvas, ScreenRect );
    finally
      DesktopCanvas.Free;
      ReleaseDc( DesktopHwnd, DesktopDC );
    end;
  end;
  Message.Result := 1;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

And the `.dfm`:

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 139
  ClientWidth = 225
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ScreenBtn: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'ScreenShot'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = ScreenBtnClick
  end
  object ExitBtn: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 40
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Exit'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = ExitBtnClick
  end
end
```

Comment: seems work :-), but how i can avoid Form "flicker" everytime that **Screenshot** button is clicked? Some idea?

Comment: I don't see any flicker except at the buttons. OTOH it doesn't surprise me if it flickers with those width and height manipulations. Solving that would be another challenge. I answered the question you asked, which was concerning the black screen.

Comment: I see now the flickering, if I open more apps and windows in general. It is a genuine problem.